# ThumbnailUtils.createImageThumbnail() has been added in API 29 but it works in API 23. How's it possible?

Tags: android

I want to create thumbnail from the images that are stored in the internal storage. According to the google documentation, in the API level 29 and above I can use `createImageThumbnail (String filePath, int kind)` and `createImageThumbnail (File file, Size size, CancellationSignal signal)` methods, Although it has been mentioned that the first method is deprecated. Now my first question is that despite of the deprecation of the first method, but it works in the API level 23(Android 6). Why?
Is it safe to use this method(first method) in API levels below 29?

My second question is that according to the google documentation the method `createImageThumbnail (String filePath, int kind)` is added in the API level 29 and also is deprecated in the API level 29. How's it possible? (I think that the API level that this method is added is mentioned wrongly. if I'm right, what's the API level that the method has been added?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a documentation bug. I downloaded the source code of API level 16 (in Android Studio -> Menu -> Tools -> SDK Manager). After opening `<ANDROID_SDK_PATH>/sources/android-16/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.java` you will discover: `createImageThumbnail(String filePath, int kind){..}` but will not find the second method (`createImageThumbnail (File file, Size size, CancellationSignal signal)`).
So a compat implementation could look like this:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
suspend fun createImageThumbnailCompat(file: File, kind: Int, size: Size): Bitmap? = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    return@withContext try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            suspendCancellableCoroutine<Bitmap?> { continuation ->
                val cancelSignal = CancellationSignal()
                continuation.invokeOnCancellation { cancelSignal.cancel() }
                continuation.resume(ThumbnailUtils.createImageThumbnail(file, size, cancelSignal))
            }
        } else {
            ThumbnailUtils.createImageThumbnail(file.absolutePath, kind)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(Tags.TAG_SYS, "Unable to create thumbnail", e)
        null
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to convert the `int kind` to `Size` you can use this method: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:packages/providers/MediaProvider/apex/framework/java/android/provider/MediaStore.java;l=2217;drc=78c9a56fe00dc47f0e010fbabd5b7953df0ce101;bpv=0;bpt=1

Comment: Many thanks for your help.